# Automatic API call Binance, please :)

Tags: json, api, url, binance

I'm looking for a way to make an automatic API call request every hour, do you know if it is possible?

For example, I would like to make call for this API: `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr` every hours but there is an automatic way to do this?

Thx a lot to everyone!

Comment: When you say "every hours", do you mean "every hour" or do you mean "Every N hours" as in "I would like to call binance every 3 hours?"  Please edit your post to reflect which of these alternatives is the case.

Comment: Thx to everyone, and I m sorry, my english it is not so good. I mean every hour, every 1 hour. I resolve anyway, thx for help!!

Comment: And re-edited accordingly.

If my answer below helped, could you upvote and/or accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is going to depend on exactly how you're making the request and how you're processing the data as follow-up, but [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is going to be the default place to start.

So if you have `binance_reader.py`

1. `sudo apt-get install cron` on Ubuntu, adjust for your local package manager elsewhere
2. `crontab -e`
3. To run this every hour, insert `0 * * * * absolute_path_to_my_binary/binance_reader.py`

Most cloud implementations will let you do something like this as well without needing a machine running 24/7/365.  For example, AWS Lambda lets you use both [cron syntax in the lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html) as well as Cloudwatch triggers on a timer.